# TYPO3 restricted page is accessible from url

Tags: typo3

I am using TYPO3 and i have a restricted area for members.

If a **guest** knows the URL of a restricted page in the members area, he is able to see its content. That's not the way it should be.

Do you know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a restricted area, you should have at least one **FE usergroup** created and this usergroup should be assigned at **Access** tab of your members only page. If you want subpages of this page to be restricted as well, you have to set **Extend to subpages** checkbox on that tab.